# Remove characters between two specific delimiters in Swift, handling nested results

Tags: ios, regex, swift, range

I have a string that I want to strip of everything in-between two specific characters. For example given `"hello {there} world"` I want to remove everything between `{` and `}` including those delimiters, in order to obtain `"hello world"`. It needs to handle the scenario where there are any number of nested results for that pattern. For example `"hello {there {mr} } world and {all} those who inhabit it"` should become `"hello world and those who inhabit it"`.

It seems it needs to find the inner most result and work its way outwards to prevent removing incorrect ranges. For example if it simply found the first `{` and the first `}` it would generate `hello  world and those who inhabit it` which is incorrect. If it were to remove everything in-between the first `{` and the last `}`, it would remove content that shouldn't be removed and result in `"hello those who inhabit it"`.

So how can this be accomplished?

One could use the `rangeOfString` API to get the first occurrence of a string and use those ranges to remove characters via  `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange`, or perhaps one could use a regex pattern. I'm not sure how best to utilize those to obtain the necessary behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward counting algorithm should work:

- Prepare an empty string for the result
- Initialize a counter to zero
- Go through characters of the input string one at a time
- When the character is an opening brace, increment the counter
- When the character is a closing brace, decrement the counter
- For all other characters check the counter. If it is zero, copy the character into the output; otherwise, skip the character

Here is a sample implementation:

```
let s = "hello {there {mr} } world and {all} those who inhabit it"
var res = ""
var count = 0
for c in s {
    switch c {
    case "{": count++; break;
    case "}": count--; break;
    default:
        if count == 0 {
            res += String(c)
        }
        break;
    }
}
println(res)
```

Modify this to make sure the `count` never goes below zero to make sure the braces are balanced in the input.

Comment: I like this approach - simple. Thanks